# Loading lines on PCA SNP plot from pcadapt

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I'm trying to add loading lines of the SNPs from a PCA I created with ggplot2 and pcadapt to see which SNPs are influential in cluster division. I see that pcadapt output has the loading data, but I am interested to see how to add this to the PCA plot. My PCA plot code is

```
pca <- ggplot(oyster.pca.df, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, colour=pop)) + 
  geom_point(size=2) +
  stat_ellipse(level = 0.95, size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  theme_bw()
```

Haven't tried anything specific yet, but google and stack overflow searches have yielded no results for how to complete this.

Comment: Please provide an example of your data, perhaps by using `dput()` to make your issue reproducible.